# Meteor - Reference a directory outside of the docker image for persistent file storage

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, docker, docker-machine

I am working on a project that requires image/file uploads. The project is built with meteorJs and I am using ostrio:files package for file upload. 
If the uploaded files are not stored outside the app build directory, the files will be deleted. So for persistent file storage, i need to store in a directory outside the build folder.

This works fine on my local machine (Windows 10) since I can easily reference a path within my machine. but when I deploy the Meteor app to the server using MUPX, I find it difficult to reference the server's root directory because the app is wrapped in a docker container.

Any idea on how I can reference the root/ any folder on the host machine from within docker? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Docker volume when deploying. It places a folder outside docker container and keeps all your files there. Also I will recommend to use `mup` instead of `mupx` as it works perfectly for me. All you need to do is to update your `mup` setup and it will do all the job for you.

Here is it:

```
module.exports = {

  // ...

  meteor: {
    name: 'app',
    path: '../app',
    volumes: { // lets you add docker volumes (optional)
      "/host/path": "/container/path",
      "/second/host/path": "/second/container/path"
    },
    //...
  },

  // ...

};
```

As you see, you can add multiple data volumes and use them with your meteor app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please can you share you `mup.js` file content with me.  I still use Meteor 1.3.5.1 because that's the last version that works with mupx. I tried using mup with my 1.4 project but it didn't work

Comment: sure https://gist.github.com/ababba15/5e51d62884a16087d1273ad0abca5d22

this config works for me now

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it

Comment: Bumping into this thread. How does one go about mounting multiple volumes and using them accordingly in the app ?

I have an `/uploads` folder at project root, but need to access the `/host/path/uploads` in my client for displaying assets.

Can't figure this out yet from running my app inside a Docker container, and in dev environment.